# PHP String Concatenation with variable integration

Tags: php

I am new to PHP after 15 years working in Classic ASP, and I am having trouble already with such basics as concatenation.  Please can you help my decipher what is wrong with this please:

```
$pstr_out .= '<a href="pg='.$pg-1.'" id="Page'.$pg-1.'Link">&laquo;&nbsp;Previous</a>&nbsp;\r';
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to concatenate an expression, use brackets

```
$pstr_out .= '<a href="pg='. ($pg-1) .'" id="Page'. ($pg-1) .'Link">&laquo;&nbsp;Previous</a>&nbsp;\r';
echo $pstr_out;
```

Answer (score 1):

most prabably the $pg-1 part

Depends on the error given by PHP

```
$pstr_out .= '<a href="pg='.($pg-1).'" id="Page'.($pg-1).'Link">&laquo;&nbsp;Previous</a>& nbsp;\r';
```

Comment: i see @chandresh_cool already gave the same answer (with an unnecessary variable though)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
 $pg-1
```

Do this

```
$page = $pg-1;


$pstr_out .= '<a href="pg='.$page.'" id="Page'.$page.'Link">&laquo;&nbsp;Previous</a>& nbsp;\r';
```

Answer (score 0):

What it have to be

Once you have got all your data ready, start with printing it out

```
<a href="pg=<?=$pg?>" id="Page<?=$pg?>Link">&laquo;&nbsp;Previous</a>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = $pg-1;
    $pstr_out .= '<a href="pg='.$x.'" id="Page'.$x.'Link">&laquo;&nbsp;Previous</a>&nbsp;\r';
```

Answer (score 0):

The real reason you get a parse error is specifically because php thinks that `1.'string'` is a float with a decimal point that then gets messed up. You need a space after an integer + period combination: `1 . 'string'`.

Worse than that, just adding the spaces isn't enough - you do need the parentheses as well, to not confuse php with the concatenation vs. arithmetic: `'<a href="pg=' . ($pg - 1) . '" id="Page' . ($pg - 1) .'Link">&laquo;&nbsp;Previous</a>&nbsp;\r'`.

Finally, the '\r' you have at the end is wrong for 2 reasons:

1. You really probably don't want \r - you want either \n (*nix/mac) or \r\n (windows).
2. You have it in single quotes. Control characters are only parsed in double quotes, so you need "\n" or "\r\n", or you get a literal backslash + letter in your output.